# JOOQ - Generate text[] as List<String>

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven, jooq-codegen

Is it possible to force Jooq to generate a List instead of a text[] when generating entities from an SQL schema?

I've tried with forced types however no luck, best I can get is an Object[]. Documentation is very poor if anyone knows anything?

Comment: What have you tried specifically?